# How can I get an updated server parameter to take effect in Azure Database for MySQL?

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

In the Azure portal I set the value of server parameter `lower_case_table_names` to `2` and successfully saved, but when I login to the server the change is not reflected:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower%';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_file_system | ON    |
| lower_case_table_names | 1     |
+------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.26 sec)
```

What can I do for this change to take effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to trigger a server restart, the problem is, as far as I remember, that **Azure Database for MySQL** doesn't support it directly.

The workaround is to scale the **vCores** of the server up and then back down to trigger a restart.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Silly though, that it can only be done via such a workaround.

Comment: It's a pending feature as far as I understand